# How to delete folders created older than last 7 days with C#?

Tags: c#, directory, exists

The folder structure is Year/Month/Day. For example, in 'C:\folder\2022\09' there are folders named 1 to 30 (because there are 30 days in august). Likewise, in the next days, a folder will be created every day, and its name will only be the number of that day, for example 'C:\folder\2022\09\19' for the file created today.
When the 'sample.exe' that I want to create with c# is run, it will delete the folders created older than the last 7 days and will not touch the folders created in the last 7 days. How can I do that ?

Comment: What have you done so far? Any code?

Comment: If you have the file paths you should look into the [aptly named function for checking the creation date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.getcreationtime?view=net-6.0), use the DateTime API to check how many days have past compared to `DateTime.Now` and then delete them if they are over 7 days

Comment: Unfortunately, because the folder structure is year/month/day, I couldn't set up an algorithm in my head.

Comment: Get a list of all subfolders then remove the ones you don't want to delete from that list and then iterate over the list and remove those folders and its contents.

Comment: @Narish I assume he meant 7 days according to his foldernames not the creation date of the folder according to the filesystem.

Comment: Ralf is right. Sometimes Windows does not update the modified date of the folder it is attached to, even though a file has been changed in it. I did it this way at first, but my teacher didn't accept it.

Comment: If that is the case, you should build the path string yourself and get the directory that way. `Datetime.Now` - 7 days, build the path, and access the dir, delete as needed. @MahsunIşık please provide a code snippet of what you have attempted so far so we have better clarity of what you intend to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes you are measuring the date based on the name of the folder and it's parents, not the metadata of the folder(s).

Gather a list of all the possible folders to delete, and get the full paths.

```
string directoryPath = @"C:\folder\2022\09\19";
```

If you're lazy and only intend on this being ran on Windows, split by backslash.

```
string[] pathSegments = directoryPath.Split('\\');
```

The last element represents the day. The second to last represents the month, and the third to last represents the year. You can then construct your own DateTime object with that information.

```
DateTime pathDate = new DateTime(
    year: int.Parse(pathSegments[^3]),
    month: int.Parse(pathSegments[^2]),
    day: int.Parse(pathSegments[^1])
);
```

You can now easily compare this DateTime against `DateTime.Now` or any other instance.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems to work, but I've written with a bat file before. I have a hollow project that I created with C#. How can I implement the code you wrote?

Comment: I've given you the tools you need to inspect a folder's absolute path and determine the date encoded in the folder structure. That's what this post is about. You still need to list all the folders you're interested in and run the delete command when you find a matching one. All that is _your_ assignment to do, I'm going giving you the entire fish for free.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is about it.

```
int limit = 7;

foreach (string dir in Directory.GetDirectories(yourPath))
{
   DateTime createdTime = new DirectoryInfo(dir).CreationTime;
   if (createdTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-limit))
   {
       Directory.Delete(dir);
    }
 }
```

Comment: See comments above. Its about the date encoded in the folder names.

Comment: @Ralf If the folders are created every day with the day encoded in the path name, deleting them by creation time in days has the same effect.

Answer (score -1):

Just get the folder name with `Directories.GetDirectories(yourPath)` then parse the folder names.  You can use `string[] date = String.Split('\\')` and then

```
int year = date[0];
int month = date[1];
int day = date[2];
DateTime folderDate = new DateTime(year, month, day);
```

Then you can just check if that date is 7 days behind `DateTime.Now` and delete the necessary folders using `Directory.Delete(folderPath);`

Comment: You need to `int.Parse()` the elements from `date`. In addition, `date[0]` in the example above will be `C:`, which is not a valid year.